# WhatsApp not working with mobile data S7 Edge

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

I use a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge with Android 6.0.1 . My WhatsApp works perfectly over wifi, However when I switch to mobile data it stops working.

I have Googled and found some "solutions" that do not work and have things to do with APN manipulation. Other "solutions" found on Google only seem to have worked on older Android versions, but have no effect here. I want to know what's wrong and how to fix this problem

Comment: Does the browser work fine over mobile data

Comment: @Abochur yes it does

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed/ pre-installed any *firewall* app, which is preventing WhatsApp from using mobile data.

Comment: I don't have any firewall apps